validate json schema in jmeter following 54575805, getting error
This is the error i got
Assertion error:true
Assertion failure:false
Assertion failure message:javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script12.groovy: 2: Unexpected input: '(' @ line 2, column 114.
.io.FileUtils.readFileToString(n
This is the code i built in jsr223 assertion
def schemaPath = 'C:\\QA\\PerformanceTesting\\CDIDashboard\\schema.json'
def rawSchema = new org.json.JSONObject(new org.json.JSONTokener(org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToString(n
ew File(schemaPath), 'UTF-8')))
def schema = org.everit.json.schema.loader.SchemaLoader.load(rawSchema)
schema.validate(new org.json.JSONObject(prev.getResponseDataAsString()))


Groovy compiler doesn't tolerate line breaks inside functions, you need to move the stuff from 3rd line to 2nd line like:
def schemaPath = 'C:\\QA\\PerformanceTesting\\CDIDashboard\\schema.json'
def rawSchema = new org.json.JSONObject(new org.json.JSONTokener(org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(schemaPath), 'UTF-8')))
def schema = org.everit.json.schema.loader.SchemaLoader.load(rawSchema)
schema.validate(new org.json.JSONObject(prev.getResponseDataAsString()))

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?

Thank you Ivan, issue resolved. I have one more question Schema validation not returning error when response data was empty like data[].
